Running fedora 41 and need to cap the max refresh rate at n hz, 60 specifically
I have Wayland running which also uses Mutter. I have been searching for quite a while and can't find anyway to lock this in.
The reason I need this done is when I shut my laptop, or other random times, changes the configured refresh rate for my external monitor, which is a pain, and required manual intervention each time.
If anyone has any luck with this please let me know. TLDR, I need to force a refresh rate in linux (fedora 41/gnome), I can see the bios/firmware screens fine.
